# Adobe Business catalyst contact form notification email chaned

Tags: business-catalyst

In my website, I want to change the contact web form notification email, Is it possible to change the notification email in Adobe Business Catalyst and how? anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of notification emails: the Autoresponder, which goes to the person who submitted the form, and the Workflow Email, which goes to the admin person you delegate.

To edit the Autoresponder, go to Site Manager > Web Forms, click on your form and then click the **Autoresponder** button.

To edit the Workflow email, go to Site Settings > System E-Mails and under the Workflow heading select **Workflow Notification**.